# How to check if coords(x,y) are valid on a board in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
isValid :: CoOrd -> Bool
```

Where `CoOrd` is a tuple pair `(x,y)`

The boards size is `['a'..'h']` `['1'..'8']` so I want to check if the given `CoOrds` are valid for this board `(CoOrds x < ['a'..'h'], CoOrds y ['1'..'8'])`

I'm fine with the logic of this question, its just the syntax as I'm new to haskell, so I'm looking for something like this

```
if (CoOrd(x _) == ['a'..'h'])
    if (CoOrd(_ y) == ['1'..'8'])
        return True
else return False
```

Comment: ```isValid (x,y) = x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` ['1'..'8']```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach is to use direct comparisons:

```
isValid :: CoOrd -> Bool
isValid (x,y) = x >= 'a' && x <= 'h' && y >= '1' && y <= '8'
```

A more advanced alternative is to exploit `Data.Ix.inRange`:

```
import Data.Ix
isValid :: CoOrd -> Bool
isValid = inRange (('a','1'),('h','8'))
```

You can also use `elem`, as others pointed out, but `elem` will scan the whole list and perform pointwise comparisons (8+8 comparisons, in the worst case), while the methods above will only do four comparisons.

Finally, a few comments on your original code:

- Don't use `return` in Haskell unless you are writing monadic code
- Don't use `if condition then True else False` -- that's noise, and it is equivalent to `conditions`. Consider using boolean operators instead, which is often simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make some new types for your X and Y coordinates so the type checker gives you a static guarantee that any `CoOrd` value is correct?

For example, I think you have `type CoOrd = (Char,Int)`.  Instead try:

```
data XCo = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Enum)
data YCo = Y1 | Y2 | Y3 | Y4 | Y5 | Y6 | Y7 | Y8 deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum)

instance Show YCo where
    show y = show (fromEnum y + 1)

type CoOrd = (XCo,YCo)
```

And now anywhere you were using character literals like `'a'`, `'b'` etc you use `A`, `B` etc.  Same with the numbers and the Y axis - `1` becomes `Y1` etc.

Comment: While this would give a guarantee that the code in the program can't use an invalid coord, you would still need some validation for input? Also, I wonder if not allowing invalid points might make some things harder. For example, if it were chess, then handling positions a knight can move to would be more tricky?

Comment: I don't see how knight moves would become tricky - you can leverage the types to provide safe primitives (such as `safe{To,From}Enum`) and therefore force checking of for boundary conditions.  And yes, you certainly can't guarantee a user doesn't type something invalid so you still need input validation - the type obviates need for validation which was needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
isValid (x,y) = x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` ['1'..'8']
```

Comment: I get an error `Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Char'`

Comment: @Dave Well in your question you showed the `y` coordinates as letters `'1'` through `'8'`.  And the error you post (you could also have posted the line the error is from too) suggests you are trying to use numbers for `y` coordinates (`1`, `2` etc).  Try `'1'` if you're using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers instead of using tuples you may define a new type, for example `ChessBoard`.

Since you are in need of checking the validity of the entered position it might be wise to make it `Maybe ChessBoard` type as well.

Accordingly you may come up with something like

```
module ChessBoard (ChessBoard, chessBoard) where

data ChessBoard = CB Char Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

chessBoard :: Char -> Int -> Maybe ChessBoard
chessBoard c n | elem c ['a'..'h'] && elem n [1..8] = Just (CB c n)
               | otherwise                          = Nothing
```

Here as you may notice we are not exporting the data constructor `CB Char Int` so the only way to create your chess board position data is through the `chessBoard` function and there will be no illegal board positions.

I mean;

```
*Main> chessBoard 'a' 3
Just (CB 'a' 3)
*Main> chessBoard 'h' 9
Nothing
*Main> let pos = Just (CB 'a' 11) -- trying to assign an illegal position directly

<interactive>:259:17: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: CB :: Char -> Integer -> a
```